# Investigating the change in a proportion/ratio

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-visualization

I want to apologise in advance if this question seems a bit vague, but I'm not sure how is the best way to ask it. On the other hand I'm pretty sure this must be a common scenario so I hope to get answers !

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID  time    treatment
1   1   A
2   1   A
3   2   B
4   3   A
5   3   A
6   3   A
7   3   B
8   4   B
9   4   A
10  5   A
11  6   B
12  7   B
13  7   A
14  7   A
15  7   B
16  8   A
17  8   B
18  9   B
19  10  B
20  11  A
21  11  A
22  12  B
23  13  B
24  14  B
24  15  A
25  16  B
26  16  A
27  18  B
28  19  B
29  19  A
30  20  B
31  21  B
32  22  B
33  22  A
34  23  B
35  24  B
36  25  B
37  26  A
38  26  B
39  27  B
40  27  B
```

My real dataset is much bigger than this.

I am interested in the general question:
How has the ratio A/B changed over time ?

To Answer this, I thought about just splitting the data into equal time periods, calculating A/B for each period and plotting them. But I noticed there is a big dependence of this on the time period I choose. Maybe that can't be avoided ? What other ways might I investigate this graphically ?  The next question is whether the proportion has changed in a "significant" way from one period to the next (or perhaps from the start to the end). If the data were just divided into two, then I guess a simple t test would suffice, but I'm really thinking about many periods - perhaps 5 or 20, but other periods are also of interest - the data spans 5 years, so annual, quarterly, monthly, weekly and even daily periods could be considered.  Are time series methods appropriate here ? I know nothing about time series at present - but it's something I am wanting to turn my eye to sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sequence of As and Bs forms a time series, why not plot the ratio as a time series.  This should show graphically how the ratio changes with time.  Also a formal test for trend in the series would probably be a better way to formally test for change than to arbtrarily split the series into two segments.

Since you point out that your time intervals are too small to capture both A and B counts for the numberator and denominator in your time series perhaps taking groups of say 7 time units will work. This of course does shorten the series and make it more like your splitting the data approach.  But if the original series is large dividing it by 7 may still give a reasonably lengthy series.  I think a fixed number like 7 would be necessary but it may not completely overcome the problem of a 0 in the numerator or the denominator.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really sure what you mean. Sometimes there are only 1 treatment per day (so the ratio is either 0 or undefined. Mostly there are 2 treatments per day: AA=undefined, AB=1/2, BB=0. Plotting these doesn't seem to make sense - it only makes sense over a longer time period - but how to choose the period ?

Comment: Thanks for your update. This makes sense to me, but may I ask: Is there any reason you chose 7 ?

Comment: No real strong reason.  I was originally going to say 5 but with 28 points 7 divides it evenly.  I think the idea is to take enough to avoid the 0 in numerator or denominator problem and not more.Just scanning through your data it seemed that 7 might be about right for that (but could be 6 or maybe a little more than 7).